# Shiny R renderText paste new line and bold

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following:

```
output$count <- renderText({
#some input

    paste("Your length is:" , input$length , "Your weight is:" , weight , 
"Your age is:", age)
```

I want to have three sentences, normally I would use sep="\n", but that's not working. How can I use \n or any other method to get a new line in my paste?
Edit: I also would like to get the answer in bold, is that possible?

Comment: try with `paste` argument `collapse="<BR>"`

Comment: shiny generates HTML, bold is `<B> ... </B>`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Something like this?

app.R

```
    library(shiny)

    ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(


       titlePanel("HTML"),


       sidebarLayout(
          sidebarPanel(
             textInput("length",
                         "Enter your length:"),
             textInput("weight",
                       "Enter your weigth:")

          ),


          mainPanel(
                  htmlOutput("testHTML")
          )
       )
    ))


    server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

       output$testHTML <- renderText({
               paste("<b>Your length is: ", input$length, "<br>", "Your weight is: ", input$weight, "</b>")
       })
    })


    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know htmlOutput could be used! answered both my questions :)

Comment: Hi Mr. Valter Beaković, great answer! Can I know how to display the input values in color? FOr example value of  ``` input$length``` and ```input$weight```  in red?