# How to add subscript or superscript to renderText in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way to add html text formatting (such as superscript or subscript) to the output of `renderText()`.  It seems that `html` tags don't work in this context.

Minimal example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Subscript test"),
    mainPanel(textOutput("test"))
    )

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$test <- renderText("CO<sub>2</sub>")
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: is this substitutable for you use case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39985307/shiny-r-rendertext-paste-new-line-and-bold/39985584

Comment: Change `textOutput()` to `htmlOutput()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code just needs the `textOutput()`  in the `ui` section to be changed to `htmlOutput()`. The latter function is specifically designed to return a reactive variable as HTML output, which allows for the usage of HTML tags among others.

More info here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.11.1/htmlOutput.html